# getenv() does not return last backslash

Tags: c++, batch-file

I am trying to read a env variable using getenv() in C++,

lets say env variable is

```
CONTENT_PATH=C:\Users\rat\Documents\fix\plat\gen\content\
```

It is being set by a batch file before program runs, contents of batch file.

```
set mypath=%~dp0
set gameContent=%mypath%plat\gen\content\

:: setting CONTENT_PATH 
setx -m CONTENT_PATH "%gameContent%"
```

during debugging in visual studio, I am getting value as

```
C:\Users\rat\Documents\fix\plat\gen\content"
```

the last '\' is not coming, even though if I manually set the env variable value using Control Panel->Advance system settings.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Seem to be missing the C++ code

Comment: I suggest that `set` or `setx` is removing it, rather than `getenv()`. Have a look in the Registry to establish that one way or the other.

Comment: Your batch file needs to use `set` in addition to setx.exe if it's setting an environment variable to be used by a child of the current CMD shell. setx.exe is used to update the registry and send a notification to top-level windows, which has nothing to do with the current shell instance or any of its child processes. CMD doesn't own a window to even see the notification from setx.exe. Like most console processes it just uses standard I/O.